# Flexible field list names in django models class

Tags: django, django-models

Instead of dynamically altering a models file by adding fields, very bad i've been told, i'm suppose to maintain a type of flexibility by having variable field list names(i think).

Thus, when an attribute is added to the database, this attribute can be accessed without the models file being altered.

I cant figure out how to create variable field list names in my models class though.
I'm having trouble sifting through reading materials to find a solution to my problem, and trial and era is 15hrs and counting.

Could some one point me in the right direction.

New Edit

Heres what im trying to achieve.

When an attribute is added, i add it to the table like this.

```
    c = 'newattributename'

    conn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'jamie', '########', 'website')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("alter table mysite_weightsprofile add column %s integer not null; SET @rank=0; UPDATE mysite_weightsprofile SET %s = @rank:=@rank+1 order by %s DESC;" %  (c, c, a))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Now, in my models class i have

```
class WeightsProfile(models.Model):
    1attributes = models.IntegerField()
    2attributes = models.IntegerField()
    3attributes = models.IntegerField()

class UserProfile(WeightsProfile):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    aattributes = models.CharField()
    battributes = models.CharField()
    cattributes = models.CharField()
```

Now all i want to do is get access to the new attribute that was added in the table but not added to in the models file.

Does sberry2A have the right answer. I hope it is, it seems the simplest.

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave examples of what exactly you are trying to do (Model that represents X needs attributes for Y because Z). Without context it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: ok, ill give one after dinner

Comment: Mixing raw SQL to create tables and the ORM to query them is a recipe for many late nights of debugging, IMO. Keep it simple, which is why sberry's answer makes most sense if you want to stick with MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might not be following what you are asking, but assuming you have some model, like Person, which will start out having some defined fields, but may have several more added in the future...

```
class Person(models.Model):

    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    # more fields to come
```

Then you could use a PersonAttribute model...

```
class PersonAttribute(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then you could just add a ManyToMany relationship field to your Person...

```
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(PersonAttribute)
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Might not have stated what i am looking for properly by the looks of things. Essentially, you start out with the above, user does something and maybe, eye color or toenail length, or even the length of ones eyelashes, is all added to the mysql database. I want a way of accessing those attributes on the fly without ever retouching the models file.

Comment: This example does exactly that: `PersonAttribute`s are arbitrary key / value strings (though it's missing a foreign key to `Person`). You should really consider flattening your data as much as possible though : )

Comment: You could use a JSONField (see django-extensions) to store whatever you like in a Text blob pretending to be JSON, but you won't be able to query the database for it. If you were using Postgres, I'd suggest checking out its funky hstore key-value support.

Comment: i look into this then, see if i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what it is you're trying to do, but [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is a good system for handling changes to models. It makes migrations, so that it understands the changes you've made and knows how to change them in the database in a way that you can use for both development sites and production.

Comment: Cheers ill look into it. The frustrating thing is i know there is some elegant simple solution to what i want within django itself, i just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're after either, JT, but I really doubt South (see @Dougal) is going to help you if what you want boils down to "Look at the relevant DB table to know what fields the model should have at read time. But not write time.". South is brilliant for evolving schemas/models, but not at runtime, and not inconsistently across rows/instances of models. And hacking models at runtime is definitely a world of hurt.

Indeed, Django's ORM isn't built for dynamic fields (at least for now) - it was built to abstract writing SQL and speed up dev against an RDBMS, not schemaless/NoSQL stuff.

Speaking of which, if someone landed me with a spec that effectively said "We don't know what fields the model will have to store" I'd suggest we try MongoDB for that data (alongside Postgres for trad relational data), probably via [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org)

Comment: damn, that just made life a little more difficult.

Comment: sberry's solution (currently above) is a MySQL-compatible, ORM-friendy  way of doing what you want. Yes, it'll result in a heap of joins in queries, but I'd bet that you're not worrying about performance for dynamic data, else you'd already be thinking Mongo/Cassandra/nonrel. So, I'd go with what he suggests.